# First of aggregate function in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a database to manage the office licensing for office computers. We reimage them frequently and must keep track of the keys we use.

I have three tables; LicenseKeyTB, SeatsAvailableTB, and ProductTB. The ProductTB contains the product name, and unique key. There will be multiple license keys for one product.

The license key table will have the license key, reference to the productTB, and a reference to the SeatsAvailableTB.

There are a certain number of seats available for a set of license keys. E.g. we have 10 seats available for 2 different license keys for Office 2010 and Office 2013. So we could give out 6 2010 licenses and 4 2013 licenses and vice versa but we cannot go over 10.

I need to select the first license key for each product with a certain number of seats available.

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
GO
select
    *
from RX.ProductTB p

JOIN(
    SELECT l.*,
    row_number() over (Partition By l.ProductID Order By l.ProductID) as Ranking
    From RX.LicenseKeyTB l
    ) as LicenseRanking
    on LicenseRanking.ProductID = p.ProductID and LicenseRanking.Ranking = 1
GO
```

This statement selects the first license key for each product. What I need is to select the product name, the first license key, and the seatsavailable where the seatsavailable is atleast a certain amount.

Comment: Add a where clause to your subquery.

Comment: How can I do a subquery where I select the min 'Ranking' where 'SeatsAvailable'>someamount? Sorry, I haven't done this before.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a join to SeatsavaibleTB ?

```
GO
select
    *
from RX.ProductTB p

JOIN(
    SELECT l.*,
    row_number() over (Partition By l.ProductID Order By l.ProductID) as Ranking
    From RX.LicenseKeyTB l
    join RX.SeatsAvailableTB s ON l.reference = s.id
    WHERE s.number > 0
    ) as LicenseRanking
    on LicenseRanking.ProductID = p.ProductID and LicenseRanking.Ranking = 1
GO
```

This way, the rank 1 ProductID will have SeatsAvailableTB.number > 0

Comment: This should work. One recommendation I would make for both your query and the original is to have filtering criteria in the where clause instead of the join condition. It makes is immediately clear what it is trying to do.

Comment: Fine, change ```join RX.SeatsAvailableTB s ON l.reference = s.id and s.number > 0``` by ```join RX.SeatsAvailableTB s ON l.reference = s.id WHERE s.number > 0```

Comment: LOL. It works the same either way and you already had my +1. :)